# How to migrate workflows from SP 2007 to SP 2010?

Tags: workflow, migration, 2007

Apparently if you do an export/import, workflows are not carried over.  Does anyone know of a way to move these from a 2007 environment over to a 2010 environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting them.  As far as I can tell there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010setup/thread/5304b7b9-00e4-4ed5-b012-934fdb1aa457) link might be of some help.

Comment: While your answer may answer the question it lacks extra content, just an external link is of no real use as they tend to break easily, try and cite some of the content and explain what is in the link that solves the issue. Also please refer to the [FAQ][1] for more information on how to post here. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

We built a tool that can copy SharePoint Designer Workflows between 2007 and 2010 sites. Give it a try with your Workflows. We have 15 days free trial. MetaVis Migrator for SharePoint: http://www.metavistech.com

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: We require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.